# how to pull flash video from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, flash, dynamic

im trying to pull .swf files from MySQL by using PHP, ive set everything in the database up with an ID and licked it properly. Im not sure if the 'type' has to be anything special, right now its just a 'VARCHAR' and when altering the javascript part of it that that flash automatically generated-- in the  i tried to echo it out by putting it in the value like

```
             < param name="movie" value="<?php echo $row['video_path']; ?>" />
```

but thats not working

Comment: I took the embed code out, I don't think it's necessary for the solution

Comment: `and licked it properly.` I have *no* idea what you mean by that :)

Comment: What does `$row["video_path"]` contain exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<object width="550" height="400">
<param name="movie" value="<?php echo $row['video_path']; ?>">
<embed src="<?php echo $row['video_path']; ?>" width="550" height="400">
</embed>
</object>
```

I hope this is what you are trying. You getting the video path from mysql ..

Comment: you helped me out soooooooooooooooooooo much thank you, thank you, thank you~~